# Concatenated Xpath return empty item

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a problem with Scrapy, the following spider return an empty item after calling `scrapy crawl panini` ,  the code of the parse of the spider `name` is:

```
class PaniniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "panini"
    start_url = ["http://comics.panini.it/store/pub_ita_it/magazines.html"]

    # products-list
    def parse(self, response):
        # Get all the <a> tags
        item = ComicscraperItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="products-list"]/div/div[2]/h3/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="products-list"]/div/div[2]/h3/a/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

This is what the crawl return:

```
2019-08-03 21:10:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-08-03 21:10:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-08-03 21:10:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-08-03 21:10:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-08-03 21:10:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-08-03 21:10:08 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.010107,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 3, 19, 10, 8, 112158),
'log_count/INFO': 10,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 3, 19, 10, 8, 102051)}
2019-08-03 21:10:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

If i wrote in terminal `response.xpath('//*[@id="products-list"]/div/div[2]/h3/a/text()').extract()`
after has load the shell with the choosen site it return the correct result!!

I think that the problem is in concatenated xpath but i dont' know where!

Comment: In the logs you’ll notice that you never crawl anything, it’s not even fetching the start URL, so the XPath is not the issue. It looks like you have a typo: `start_url` → `start_urls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use attributes available such as `class` or `id` while scraping, it will make your life easier.

Try with below tested code:

```
for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='list-group']//h3/a"):
    print(sel.xpath('./text()').extract_first().strip(''))
    print(sel.xpath('./@href').extract_first())
```

Edit: A better version of above code:

```
for sel in response.xpath("//h3[@class='product-name']/a"):
    print(sel.xpath('./@title').extract_first())
    print(sel.xpath('./@href').extract_first())
```